# Promesas En Cadena JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, nodejs, promesas

Estoy aprendiendo sobre las Promesas ya he logrado obtener los resultados de estas con then y await, pero ahora me metí en un problema que ya no he podido resolver, les explico:

tengo estas funciones que corren por mi servidor de NodeJS

```js
//End Point para Insertar Beneficiario2
router.post('/asesores/Insertsolicitud-Ben2', (req, res) => { 
    var cad=req.body.json.toString();   
    var json=JSON.parse(cad);
    var resp="";
    for (var key=0; key<Object.keys(json).length;key++) {
        var { cliente, sol, nombre, fechanac, parentezco, porciento, calle, noint, noext, colonia, cp, municipio, entidadfed, pais } = json[key];
        var sql = "call InsertarBeneficiarios('" + cliente + "','" + sol + "','" + nombre + "','" + fechanac + "','" + parentezco + "','" + porciento + "','" + calle +
            "','" + noint + "','" + noext + "','" + colonia + "','" + cp + "','" + municipio + "','" + entidadfed + "','" + pais + "');";
        InsertaBen(sql,key).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data.key);
            if(data.key==Object.keys(json).length-1){
                resp+=data.cadenaben;
                res.json({estatus:"ready",insert:resp});
                res.status(200);
            }
            else{
                resp+=data.cadenaben;
            }
        });
        
    }  
    
    
});

async function InsertaBen(sql,key){    
    try{        
        var response={
            cadenaben:await InsertB(sql),
            key:key
        };        
        return response;
    }
    catch(e){
        return e;
    }
}

function InsertB(sql){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        mysql3.query(sql, (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (!err && isNaN(rows)) {
                var result = JSON.stringify(rows[0]); //se procesa los resultados de la consulta convirtiendolas a json
                var json = JSON.parse(result); // se hace la convesion para pasarlo a cadena de json
                if (json[0].ban == 200) {
                    console.log(sql);
                    resolve(json[0].beneficiarioid+"-");
                    
                } else {
                    reject("E");
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log(err);
                reject("E");
            }
        }); 
    });    
}
```

Como se logra apreciar, necesito capturar todas las respuestas de consulta que se hacen a mysql, estas respuestas me devuelven los Id de los beneficiarios que se insertaron en la base de datos, necesito toda esta cadena.
El proceso funciona, ya que si inserta los beneficiarios que le mando, sin embargo, el problema viene al obtener la cadena, ya que a veces solo me muestra el beneficiario 0 o el último, osea, esto provoca que la cadena no se genere con todos los beneficiarios. Yo pensaba que en el for se ejecutaban las promesas en el mismo orden, pero como son promesas asyncronas puede que el beneficiario 10 se ejecute antes que el 1, provocando que la cadena quede incompleta.

Mi pregunta concreta es, ¿como puedo controlar o asegurarme que todas estas calls se ejecuten en orden? en el mismo orden en el que se ejecuta el for,  independientemente del numero de beneficiarios.

Comment: Porque no intentas poner el controlador asincrono y usar `await InsertaBen(sql,key).then(...)`. Nota: Veo raro en tu código que el `res.json()` podría terminar ejecutandose varias veces... no da eso resultados inesperados?

Comment: @pipe gracias, actualizare el post en un rato cuando aplique los cambios y vemos si con esto queda, muchas gracias  por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo que puede estar causando este problema es que no controlar la funcion `InsertaBen` en el for

```
router.post('/asesores/Insertsolicitud-Ben2', async (req, res) => { 
    var cad=req.body.json.toString();   
    var json=JSON.parse(cad);
    var resp="";
    for (var key=0; key < Object.keys(json).length;key++) {
        var { cliente, sol, nombre, fechanac, parentezco, porciento, calle, noint, noext, colonia, cp, municipio, entidadfed, pais } = json[key];
        const sql = `call InsertarBeneficiarios(${cliente},${sol},${nombre},${fechanac},${parentezco},${porciento},${calle},${noint},${noext},${colonia},${cp},${municipio},${entidadfed},${pais});`;
      
      
        await InsertaBen(sql,key).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data.key);
            if(data.key == Object.keys(json).length - 1){
                resp+=data.cadenaben;
                res.json({estatus:"ready",insert:resp});
                res.status(200);
            }else{
                resp+=data.cadenaben;
            }
        });
        
    }  
    
    
});
```

Para poner de manera correcta el await en la función, la función padre tiene que ser asincrona, y de igual manera en los strings te recomiendo usar template strings se ve mucho mas limpio

Comment: jaja vaya quería intentar algo así, pero no sabia como poner el await dentro del for, en unas horas actualizo el post para ver si me fue de ayuda.. gracias por esta respuesta.